# Swing GridBagLayout - auto-resize fields

Tags: java, swing

This is a piece of code generated from netbeans Swing gui designer.
I'm trying to do the following: `jLabel1` and `jLabel2` will contain only image icon with dimension 52x46 px without text, they should be fixed in the left and right side of the line, `jTextField2` is expected to fill the gap between jlabels and autoresize to full screen/view width.

Problem is, that `jTextField2` remains with same width no matter what size of window/view is... The initial width is dependent on the length of hard-coded text inside the field...

Do you have any idea, how to do this?

```
private void initComponents() {
    javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;

    java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

    jLabel1.setText("ABC");
    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    getContentPane().add(jLabel1, gridBagConstraints);

    jTextField2.setText("some text field content");
    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
    gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    getContentPane().add(jTextField2, gridBagConstraints);

    jLabel2.setText("ABC");
    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    getContentPane().add(jLabel2, gridBagConstraints);

    pack();
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[See documentation of GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html)

[GridBagConstraints.weightx](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#weightx), [GridBagConstraints.weighty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#weighty)

> Used to determine how to distribute space, which is important for specifying resizing behavior. Unless you specify a weight for at least
>   one component in a row (weightx) and column (weighty), all the
>   components clump together in the center of their container. This is
>   because when the weight is zero (the default), the GridBagLayout
>   object puts any extra space between its grid of cells and the edges of
>   the container.

```
jTextField2.setText("some text field content");
gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0; //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

getContentPane().add(jTextField2, gridBagConstraints);
```